# coffee script syntax issue

Tags: coffeescript

is there anything wrong with this coffee script? Its working fine on this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Dtwigs/ThnKc/2/

but when i try to convert it to coffee script it does not want to seem to work

```
$(document).on "change", "#print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite", (event) ->
  selected = undefined
  index = undefined
  selected = $(this).val()
  index = $("select").index(this)
  if selected is "customSize"
    $($(".custom_size")[index]).fadeIn()
  else
    $($(".custom_size")[index]).fadeOut()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your fiddle.

1. You're using the same ID for multiple elements - you should make it a class.
2. You're adding the change event to the document, it's probably better to add it to a more precise selector, namely the selects.
3. If you're going to write it in JS in the first place, there's not much gain from using a CoffeeScript converter.

I've fixed some issues with the fiddle and updated it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/phenomnomnominal/ThnKc/5/).

The new CoffeeScript looks like this:

```
$(".print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite").change ->
  selected = $(this).val()
  index = $("select").index this
  func = if selected is ".custom_size" then 'fadeIn' else 'fadeOut'
  $($('.custom_size')[index])[func]()
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can see is that you write (event) here when on fiddle is (evt).

Are you considering using http://js2coffee.org/ for the conversion?